# Clicking on treeview node disappears the treeview in asp.net. Why?

Tags: asp.net, .net, treeview

I am binding the treeview control in a usercontrol. On Clicking the node, the page dosent show the treeview and Tree_Index_SelectedNodeChanged does not fire. And there is no exception catched in the application.

Any idea why ?

Actually i have used the same code to bind the treeview in aspx page and it works fine when clicking the tree node.

Here is the HTML rendered for that treeview node for both the pages which looks different. Would this be a problem ?

Treeview Binded in ASPX (Working)

```
<td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a style="text-decoration:none;" id="ctl00_cphMain_Tree_Indext3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$Tree_Index','sSheltered Homes for the Aged')">Sheltered Homes for the Aged</a></td>
```

Treeview Binded in ASCX (Not Working)

```
<td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_447647F9-47FF-4FBD-8DE3-956EB1255383_Tree_Indext3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$447647F9-47FF-4FBD-8DE3-956EB1255383$Tree_Index','sSheltered Homes for the Aged')" class="ctl00_cphMain_447647F9-47FF-4FBD-8DE3-956EB1255383_Tree_Index_0">Sheltered Homes for the Aged</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

Check using

```
if(![postback)
{

}

if(postback)
{

}
```

or check this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163598.aspx